# Non-expected result of QDir::homePath() for a program run by startproc

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have the following small program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDir>

const char * homeDir()
{
  return getpwuid(geteuid())->pw_dir;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("Qt homedir: %s\n", qPrintable(QDir::homePath()));
  printf("Native homedir: %s\n", homeDir());

  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  return a.exec();
}
```

Now:

- when run directly by a "normal" user, `./program`, the output is:

  > Qt homedir: /home/user
  >   Native homedir: /home/usr

which is ok

- when run directly by root, `./program`, the output is:

  > Qt homedir: /root
  >   Native homedir: /root

which is ok

- when run by root as a different user by the means of sudo, e.g. `sudo -u user ./program`, the output is:

  > Qt homedir: /home/user
  >   Native homedir: /home/user

which is ok

- **when run by root as a different user by the means of startproc, e.g. `startproc -u user /full/path/to/program`, the output is:**

  > Qt homedir: /root
  >   Native homedir: /home/user

which is **NOT** ok, or not expected (at least for me)

And my question is: **why does the last run give a different result than the others**? Is it a bug in Qt (doesn't take into account the fact, that the effective user is different than the real user, or something different), or am I missing some background info (e.g. the mechanism of how startproc works)?

The version of Qt in question is 5.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt's `QFileSystemEngine` uses the contents of the `HOME` environment variable on Unix - see its [implementation](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfilesystemengine_unix.cpp.html#_ZN17QFileSystemEngine8homePathEv). Yet `startproc -u` does not set `HOME`: that's why it fails.

The `getpwuid` call can be potentially very expensive and can block, i.e. by getting information from an LDAP or AD server, etc., and it's best if you take care of it yourself. Furthermore, it's not thread-safe, and you should use `getpwuid_r` instead.

An implementation might look as follows:

```
static QString getHomeDir() {
  auto const N = sysconf(_SC_GETPW_R_SIZE_MAX);
  auto *buffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(N);
  passwd pwd;
  passwd *result;
  getpwuid_r(geteuid(), &pwd, buffer.get(), N, &result);
  if (result) {
    auto *dir = result->pw_dir;
    auto const decoded = QFile::decodeName(dir);
    return QDir::cleanPath(decoded);
  }
  return {};
}

enum class HomeDir { Default, Init };
QString homeDir(HomeDir option = HomeDir::Default) {
  // needs a C++11 compiler for thread-safe initialization
  static QFuture<QString> home = QtConcurrent::run(getHomeDir);
  return (option == HomeDir::Init) ? QString() : home;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  homeDir(HomeDir::Init);
  // do other time-consuming initializations here
  QString () << homeDir();
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks, I was suspecting something similar.So is there a way to run a daemon using `startproc` so that the `HOME` envvar is set? Or what is the proper way to start a daemon with other user's privileges so I get the user's environment? I have read it's the `startproc` way but somehow I doubt it, if I'm unable to see the effective user's environment...

Comment: The HOME envvar is simply not set. Use the `homeDir` implementation above and you'll be set.